# Problems with Dart sqljocky

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to use Dart in future for developing because its very functionally.
Ive started a Project but I am getting errors if i am impporting mysqljocky.

```html
name: WebInterface
description: A web app for the popular minecraft plugin
version: 0.0.1
#homepage: https://www.example.com
#author: LarsE <email@example.com>

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0
  angular_components: ^0.8.0
  sqljocky: ^0.14.1

dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^1.0.0
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  test: ^0.12.0

transformers:
- angular:
    entry_points:
      - web/main.dart
      - test/**_test.dart
- test/pub_serve:
    $include: test/**_test.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter

# Uncomment the following in sdk 1.24+ to make pub serve
# use dartdevc (webdev.dartlang.org/tools/dartdevc).
#web:
#  compiler:
#    debug: dartdevc
```

I am getting everytime this error:

```html
Working dir: E:\WebAuction\WebInterface
"C:\Program Files\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat" get
Resolving dependencies...
Package dart_style has no versions that match >=0.2.10 <2.0.0 derived from:
- angular 4.0.0 depends on version >=0.1.8 <2.0.0
- code_builder 1.0.3 depends on version >=0.2.10 <2.0.0
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access MySQL from code running in the browser.
This is why this attempt causes an error message.
This is not related to Dart, but how SQL databases work.

You need to expose a REST API or similar on a server that forwards queries and commands to the database running on the server.
Dart server frameworks like Aqueduct, Angel, Jaguar, Shelf, can be used for that, but the server doesn't need to be written in Dart. There are lots of other solutions.

From Angular you can access the REST API using HTTP requests.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. It depends on what exactly you want to do. There are so many different ways.